# Remove Exponents from Matlab LOG-LOG plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot several frequency response curves on a logx and logy plot. I also want the axes to show values without exponents.

I cannot figure out a way to plot the log scale AND remove exponents. Using the following, I can only either set my scale to log, OR remove exponents. Not both.

```
figure(3);clf;
hold on; 

%set(gca,'YScale', 'log', 'XScale', 'log')); %This doesnt work with ax.XAxis.Exponent = 0;

plot(freq, Pxx,'r', 'LineWidth', 1.5, 'DisplayName', 'Single-Sided Spectral Density');

ax=gca;
ax.XAxis.Exponent = 0; %remove exponents
ax.YScale = 'log'; %Log Y
ax.XScale = 'log'; %Log X

xlabel('Frequency [Hz]');ylabel('[WU^2 / Hz]');
title('Average Single-Sided Spectral Density [G_x_x] vs. Frequency')
grid on;
xlim([0 max(freq)]);legend('FontSize',14);
hold off
```

[Plot with log scale, AND Exponents in scale values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD2io.png)

[Plot without log scale, without exponents in scale values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vS6h.png)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the tick labels can be done like this:

```
figure;loglog([12 123 1233],[12 144 1111]);
set(gca,'xticklabel',arrayfun(@(x) num2str(x),(get(gca,'xtick')),'un',0))
set(gca,'yticklabel',arrayfun(@(x) num2str(x),(get(gca,'ytick')),'un',0))
```